# Is it necessary to delcare helper methods in header file

Tags: ios, ios7

I have all of my helper methods at the bottom of my implementation file while not having them declared in header. Is that ok, or is it necessary to declare them in header?

Example:

```
#pragma mark - Helper Methods

- (void)reset {
  // Reset' the following properties
  //
  self.image = nil;
  self.imagePicker = nil;
  [self.recipients removeAllObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare them in the header (or even in a private, internal `@interface`) unless you need to be able to call them from other classes.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can keep them just in the implementation file.